# Netbooting bare metal nodes, pass VLAN tag to the installer

Tags: networking, 18.04, system-installation, pxe, vlan

I need to install Ubuntu 18.04 onto some bare metal nodes. I'm using the normal [Preseed + Debian Installer process](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/amd64/apbs01.html).

We use VLANs and I cannot figure out how to configure the installation image to use this VLAN for the installer.

Here's how the process works:

1. Configure the hardware NIC to use the VLAN tag (This is easy) via a firmware menu.
2. The host gets a DHCP IP and is sent to the TFTP server.
3. The TFTP server sends the installation image files to the host. The host receives it
4. The host then loads the Ubuntu installation image.
5. The installation proceeds

Steps 1-3 show that the host, network & VLAN are working.

At step #4, the installation image loads a new network configuration. However, it isn't adding a VLAN tag. It tries to get a DHCP address, but since it's not using a VLAN, the DHCP server never sees the request.

How can I pass on the VLAN tag to the installer? Is there a Kernel commandline that can be used with Ubuntu, as can be done with Fedora?

I'm very familiar with Kickstart on CentOS, but I'm fairly new to Preseed.

Ubuntu [fixed this issue in Ubuntu 19.06](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools/+bug/1382054), but I'm using 18.04.

Comment: FYI: The latest *bionic* media (18.04.5) was released this earlier month, well after 2019-June so have you tried it?

Comment: Thanks for the tip @guiverc. This is Ubuntu 18.04.5.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @guiverc. This is Ubuntu 18.04.5. It's not listed as a fix at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes/ChangeSummary/18.04.5 , but let me try it anyways.

Comment: No, this option didn't work for me. But I found another solution, which I posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was:

1. Configure the system manually
2. Configure the NIC manually
3. Run the following command to figure out what options preseed/debian-installer used for `netcfg`. Many options are not documented.
4. Append `netcfg/...` options to my Kernel command-line, as this example shows:

   ```
    LABEL linux
        KERNEL boot/ubuntu-mirror-linux
        APPEND initrd=boot/ubuntu-mirror-initrd.gz interface=auto url=http://mirrors.example.org/somefile.cfg ramdisk_size=10800 root=/dev/rd/0 rw auto ... ksdevice=bootif priority=medium netcfg/use_vlan=true netcfg/vlan_id=999
        IPAPPEND 2
   ```